# Why is PHP json_decode on JSON loaded from a database not working?

Tags: php, json, database

I am encoding JSON using `json_encode(["something" => ["hello", "world"]])` and then saving it to a database.

The database stores the JSON like so:

`{&#34;something&#34;:[&#34;hello&#34;,&#34;world&#34;]}`

when decoding this data from the database using `json_decode($data)` and then print_ring the result prints the following:

`{"something":["hello","world"]}`

I already tried the following on the data from the database before trying to decode it:

```php
$data = urldecode($data);

$data = htmlspecialchars_decode($data);

$data = str_replace("&#34;", "\"", $data);

$data = str_replace("&#34;", "\\\"", $data);

$data = str_replace("\u0022","\\\\\"", $data);
```

But without success. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: If you can't fix the issue when storing the strings, then [`html_entity_decode` should do the job](https://3v4l.org/OuHI3). I'm hesitant to add this as an answer though, since a database definitely shouldn't be escaping strings for HTML, and why that's happening in the first place should probably be your focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if i understand the problem correctly, you encode the data (becomes a string) and store it. Then you retrieve the string and decodes it. It becomes a string again?

- When you say "echo" it, are you actually using echo? (because if you are expecting it to become object or array, you actually shouldn't use echo)
- Are you storing it as UTF-8 in the database? - the JSON accepted by json_decode must be UTF8

Most likely, you should look into the string escaping on insert and retrieval. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

(always prepare statements: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: I'm actually using print_r()

Comment: I am always preparing statements and executing it with the given params. Each param is escaped using `filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS)`... I assume I have to reverse this process somehow?

Comment: @swiftlynx Right, that's the problem - remove the calls to `filter_var`. `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` is for escaping a string for display in an HTML page, it won't do anything useful for saving it to a database. You shouldn't need to decode strings again when you retrieve them, just let the DB library do the job.

Comment: This is there to prevent XSS though

Comment: Yeah, @swiftlynx got it. Dont use filter var for this. Prepare statement with the PDO driver instead https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php. Filter var is not intended for database use, and preparing the statement using execute should take care of the xss issue just fine :)

Comment: @swiftlynx Escape your strings on the way *out* of the database, not on the way in. If you're storing the escaped versions, then these are the exact problems you'll have - not being able to use them easily. Escape for XSS when you're displaying them on the page.

Comment: Using filter var should not be on the encoded string, but on the values in the array in order to make sense. You cant filter_var on a "data structure" (in this case json string)